# ddwrt Schema Unavailable?

Tags: xslt, date-time, ddwrt

## So:

I'm trying to use the ddwrt:FormatDateTime function in an XSL transform, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception details:
Method: System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.Xml.XPath.XPathItem]
InvokeXsltLateBoundFunction(System.String, System.String,
System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.Xml.XPath.XPathItem][])
Type: System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException
Source: System.Data.SqlXml
Description: Cannot find the script or external object that implements prefix 
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime'.
```

I do have the namespace defined. Here's my header (except it's all on one line in my file):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime">
```

Why would it be throwing this error? This is my first XSL transform. Is there something simple I'm overlooking?

## Note:

Following the path to the schema throws an exception when I try to navigate there from my browser... Is it just down? Is there a new schema?

Comment: Per the [FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)  we do not accept questions about commercial, third-party products.  If possible please reproduce the problem or pose the question so that it does not involve a third-party product, or ask your question using the vendor's support site if it is product-specific. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the code behind didn't register the extension... frustrating...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/2b4c89ff-f2e0-40da-9d15-f0f8e528a16f

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addextensionobject.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the lightning conductor webpart supports the ddwrt extensions.  Unfortunely, MS marked this class as internal, so, when I wanted to use them in my own XSLT, I had to reflector the code and put it into my own class and then register my own class as the extension.  I doubt that lightning tools did this but they could have.

```
XsltArgumentList xslArgs = new XsltArgumentList();
DdwRuntime runtime = new DdwRuntime();  //My own class reflectored from SharePoint
runtime.View = view;
runtime.List = list;
runtime.Web = web;
runtime.ListItem = listItem;
xslArgs.AddExtensionObject("http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime", runtime);
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured the more I read about... sadly they also didn't register the "xls:fn" extension either... what garbage. That's a massive oversight and heavily limits customization of their tool.

Comment: Steve, would you be willing to share your DdwRuntime class? I'm attempting to do the same but as usual the Microsoft classes have a lot of references to other internal or private classes. I'm curious how much you implemented?